# How to auto update properties of a doctrine entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created a doctrine entity class in my symfony 2 project and now I want to auto set a property before saving by the entity manager. Are there some hooks to implement or how can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

```
<?php

namespace MyNS\Dummy;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/  
class Dummy
{
    protected $property;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function automaticProperty()
    {
        $this->property = 'whatever';
    }
}
```